# 3 x 3 sliding puzzle

Tags: sliding-blocks

I have  a 3x3 sliding puzzle that is currently in this state:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 |  | 6 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 |

I want to solve the puzzle, so that it is in the following state:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 6 | 7 | 8 |

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Is this a puzzle you got from somewhere else? If so, then you need to provide attribution, otherwise this could be considered plagiarism.

Comment: @Stevo, it seems like this is just a standard 3x3 sliding block puzzle.  They have one that is mixed up and want to know how to solve it.

Comment: It is just a smaller variant of well known  15 puzzle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_Puzzle

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I wrote that before I understood what the puzzle was (before I edited it and realised it was a sliding puzzle).

Answer (score 0):

> For these types of puzzles, work from the top to the bottom. Try find a way to get the 1 to the top middle. One way you could do that is to move the bottom right 2 x 2 grid around clockwise until you get the 1 into the middle; then bring the 4 down and move the 2 across for the 1. [image]

> You can then use the same idea to get the 3 into the right spot; move the bottom right 2 x 2 grid clockwise until you get the 3 into the middle; then move away the 5 and the 8.[image]

> Using the same bottom right 2 x 2 to solve the 4;[image]

> Now its here where it gets tricky. We need to try get the 5 without disrupting the 3 and the 4, but  with the 7 up there we have to. The same idea is used, except this time using the bottom 3 x 2 to rotate anticlockwise, then rotating back and bring the 7 down.[image]

> Now we bring the 1 and 2 over, and the 5 and the 4 up, to make a 2 x 2 grid on the bottom left. Moving that clockwise gets us to a position where 3,4 and 5 are connected.[image]

> Now we just finish the puzzle.[image]

Comment: Since the blank space ends up at the top, why not solve it bottom to top? (Or turn it 180 degrees and solve top to bottom)

Comment: It was mainly a guide of a way to solve; by no means optimal. These sliding puzzles should be solved in some chronological order; this is one of them.